# What is the proper way to test CodeIgniter session variable?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, variables, isset

Take the following code snippet. What is the best way to test to make sure the session variable isn't empty?

```
<?php if ($this->session->userdata('userID')) {
   $loggedIn = 1;
}
else {
   $loggedIn = 0;
} ?>
```

If later in my script, I call the following, the first prints properly, but on the second I receive *Message: Undefined variable: loggedIn*

```
<?php echo $this->session->userdata('userID'));
      echo $loggedIn; ?>
```

I've tried using `!empty` and `isset`, but both have been unsuccessful. I also tried doing the if/then statement backwards using `if (!($this->session->userdata('userID'))`, but no dice. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try doing the following instead:

```
<?php 
$loggedIn = 0;
if ($this->session->userdata('userID') !== FALSE) {
   $loggedIn = 1;
}
?>
```

If the error continues, you'll need to post more code in case you're calling that variable in another scope.

Comment: It actually ended up being a problem with not passing the variables to the view I was loading (noob move!), but I appreciate the clarification anyway. Thanks friend!

Answer (score 2):

If your aim is to see whether or not the session variable `'userID'` is set, then the following should work:

```
$this->session->userdata('userID') !== false
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a boolean field in your session called is_logged_in and then check like:

```
if(false !== $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
    //then condition
}
```

This is the proper way to test!