# CodeIgniter Session is not set

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

The session is not set in the following case. It was working for me earlier.
I am using CodeIgniter.

```
 public function authenticate(){
    $user = new Entity\User;
    //$user2 = new Entity\User;
    $user->username = "prayag@gmail.com";
    $user->password = "prayag";
    $userRepository = $this->doctrine->em->getRepository('Entity\User');
    $checkLogin = $userRepository->checkLogin($user);
    echo "Username => ". $checkLogin[0]->username;
    echo "ID => ". $checkLogin[0]->id;
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->session->sess_destroy();

    if(!empty($checkLogin)){
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $this->session->set_userdata('user_id',$checkLogin[0]->id);

        $loggedIn = $this->session->set_userdata('user_id');    
            if($loggedIn !== TRUE){
                echo "session is not set";
                //echo $this->session->set_userdata('user_id');
            } else {
                    echo "session is set";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "Username not found";  
        }
    }
```

I tried to solve it using the following post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712250/w
hat-is-the-proper-way-to-test-codeigniter-session-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712250/what-is-the-proper-way-to-test-codeigniter-session-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did u load the session library

i.e. `$this->load->library('session');`

also, convert the code

```
$loggedIn = $this->session->set_userdata('user_id');    
            if($loggedIn !== TRUE){
                echo "session is not set";
                //echo $this->session->set_userdata('user_id');
            } else {
                    echo "session is set";
            }
        }
```

to

```
if($this->session->userdata('user_id')!=true)
   {
        echo "session is not set";
                //echo $this->session->set_userdata('user_id');
   } 
else 
{
    echo "session is set";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

After `$this->session->sess_destroy();`

Shouldn't be something like `session_start();` ?

Or what's the point to destroy session in the middle of code?

Comment: i tried it before in more then 3 projects it works fine there but here it is not

Comment: Can you just use `$this->session->unset_userdata($something);` instead of destroing it?

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
$loggedIn = $this->session->set_userdata('user_id');
```

to

```
$loggedIn = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
```